Autostart Pygame script using systemd
I am trying to autostart a simple pygame python script using systemd.
My raspberrypi5 is configured to autologin when starting.
Using a .desktop entry I am able to start my game, however I would like to have more control about it but am unable to do so using a systemd service.
My .desktop looks as follow and is placed in ~/.config/autostart/:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My awesome game
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/main.py

For the .service I did the following:
[Unit]
Description=My awesome game.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/main.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=xdg-desktop-autostart.target

I then placed the .service file under ~/.config/systemd/user/
and run:
systemctl --user enable mygame.service
systemctl --user start mygame.service

and the game runs successfully.
This doesn't happen when I reboot my machine.
Any clues why?
Edit 1
systemctl --user status mygame.service returns after failing to open upon boot:
magame.service - My awesome game.
    Loaded: loaded ([...]; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Active: inactive (dead)

Edit 2
journalctl --user -u mygame.service shows nothing happened after reboot.
Edit 3
I managed to get it started but now I got no image. It seems like the game is running somewhere in the background.
The service file looks like this now:
[Unit]
Description=My awesome game.

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/main.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target


Just for a start ANY systemd code runs as root. There is no user interaction.

@Milliways: NO!!

There is a separate systemd instance run for each logged in user which runs as that user.  However, users are not automagically logged in at boot unless you configure the system to do so, which you make no reference to here.  You need to incorporate some logging into your game so you can see what's going on and when and how it fails.   See the StandardOutput= option in man systemd.exec.

@goldilocks What I do is autologin to the Rpi5's desktop environment and then I want the game to start there.
